# Using Awk/Sed to substitue a the value of the matched pattern in the file

Tags: awk, sed

i have the below input in a config file

```
#bumpcase case ( BUMPCASE45678 ) some other text
fred fredm1989

chasi chasi1987

hector hector1978
#bumpcase case ( BUMPCASE3123098 ) some other text
simon sim1984

roger roger1985
```

i need to display the contents in a new file as below

```
fred fredm1989:BUMPCASE45678

chasi chasi1987:BUMPCASE45678

hector hector1978:BUMPCASE45678

simon sim1984:BUMPCASE3123098

roger roger1985:BUMPCASE3123098
```

is there any way using awk/sed to perform the same ? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, 1st- Please wrap your code into CODE TAGS by using code tags button `{}` 2nd- please add your effort(as we all are here to learn) which you made to solve this.

Comment: thanks will do , am pretty new to awk trying to work my way around

Comment: @jww downvoted the question and all answers again so I'm upvoting them all again to compensate.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is telling now that field number of string could be different so I am looking for string `BUMPCASE` here with digits in a line which starts with `#`.

```
awk '/^#/ && match($0,/BUMPCASE[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next} NF{$NF=$NF":"val} NF' Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

***Solution 1st:*** In case you want to remove empty lines.

```
awk '/^#/{val=$4;next} NF{$NF=$NF":"val} NF'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
/^#/{           ##Checking condition if a line starts from #(hash) then do following.
  val=$4;       ##Assigning a variable named val to 4th field value in current line.
  next}         ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here.
NF{             ##NF is a condition which checks if a line is NOT NULL then do following.
  $NF=$NF":"val}##Appending colon and value of variable val here to last field of line.
NF              ##NF condition checks if a line is NOT NULL then print the current line.
' Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to keep empty lines in output.

```
awk '/^#/{val=$4;next} NF{$NF=$NF":"val} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
/^#/{           ##Checking condition if a line starts from #(hash) then do following.
  val=$4;       ##Assigning a variable named val to 4th field value in current line.
  next}         ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here.
NF{             ##NF is a condition which checks if a line is NOT NULL then do following.
  $NF=$NF":"val}##Appending colon and value of variable val here to last field of line.
1               ##awk works on method of condition and action so putting 1 making condition TRUE so print of line will happen.
'  Input_file   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @shirop, added explanation too now for my both of the solutions.

Comment: thanks Ravinder  ..qq is there any way to not hardcode the $4 (4th field) ..given if there is some additional charecters before the 4th field it will break the code

Comment: sure.. since the config file is manually edited from time to time ..                a pre-defined pattern is not always followed , like below ..                                                         

{                                                                                                 #bumpcase case ( BUMPCASE45678 ) some other text
fred fredm1989

chasi chasi1987

hector hector1978

#bumpcase ( BUMPCASE3123098 ) some other text

simon sim1984

roger roger1985}

Comment: @shirop, try my EDIT code, it always looks for string `BUMPCASE` irrespectve of its place value, let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in awk:

```
awk '/^#/{bumpcase=$4}/^[^#]/{print $0":"bumpcase}' yourfile
```

Example:

```
$ cat test.txt
#bumpcase case ( BUMPCASE45678 ) some other text
fred fredm1989

chasi chasi1987

hector hector1978
#bumpcase case ( BUMPCASE3123098 ) some other text
simon sim1984

roger roger1985

$ awk '/^#/{bumpcase=$4}/^[^#]/{print $0":"bumpcase}' test.txt
fred fredm1989:BUMPCASE45678
chasi chasi1987:BUMPCASE45678
hector hector1978:BUMPCASE45678
simon sim1984:BUMPCASE3123098
roger roger1985:BUMPCASE3123098
```

Comment: Very nice thanks so much...so 'bumpcase' is the variable here where we are putting the string+num value to  substitute later during print